# Comparison between two lists of strings for finding substring in python

Tags: python, list, substring, comparison

```
import tkinter as tk
import speech_recognition as sr
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import nltk
from tkinter import *
#--------------1stfile---------------
r = sr.Recognizer()
file = sr.AudioFile("t.wav")
with file as source:
audio = r.record(source, duration=20)
result = r.recognize_google(audio)

with open("audio.txt", "w") as text_file:
  text_file.write("%s" % result)
with open("audio.txt", "r") as file:
  file_content = file.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)
print("tokens", tokens)
text_file.close()

def onclick():
 a=1
 tk.messagebox.showinfo("Phrased entered by user : ", phrase_var.get())
 str = phrase_var.get()
 list2 = list(str.split(" "))
 length=len(list2)
 count=0
 for i in tokens:
    for j in list2:
        if(j==i):
            count=count+1
            break
 print(count)
 if(length==count):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("result", " Phrase " + phrase_var.get() + 
"found in file")


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Desktop App")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.configure(bg='brown')
ttk.Label(window, text="Write phrase: ").pack()
phrase_var = tk.StringVar()
phrase_entrybox = ttk.Entry(window, width=16, 
textvariable=phrase_var).pack()
ttk.Label(window, text=result).pack()
ttk.Button(window,text="Search", command=onclick).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

i have two separate lists containing strings in it.one is bigger in size while other one is smaller in size, i want to check whether strings which are present in smaller strings of lists are present in longer or not here is some example below please help me out to find solution for it
longer list:
'['how', 'many', 'people', 'are', 'there', 'in', 'your', 'family', 'there', 'are', 'five',
'people', 'in', 'my', 'family', 'my', 'father', 'mother', 'brother', 'sister', 'and', 'me',
'house', 'in', 'the', 'countryside']'
smaller list:
['people', 'in', 'my', 'family']

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: i have tried to compare contents of both the lists but it didn't work for me

Comment: Share the code here, would be glad to help!

Comment: i have attached code sir please help me out

Comment: Sir kindly help me in another problem......
i have taken two audio files. First audio file consists of phrase that may present in second file which means that phrase present in first audio file was spoken by speaker in second audio, until now i have converted these files to text by using speech to text conversion library and find out whether phrase is present or not in second audio by tokenizing audio files now i want to check at which time slot this phrase was spoken by using dynamic time wrapping but couldn't find the way to do this kindly tell me if you know any algrithm for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `issubset` method of `set`

```
if set(smaller_list).issubset(set(larger_list)):
    ## Your code
```

This checks if all the elements present in the `smaller_list` are present in the `larger_list` as well. In short, it checks if `smaller_list` is a subset of `larger_list`

Comment: sir as i am converting audio file(english speech ) to text file and then finding phrase (string) given by the user that whether it is present in that file or not, so if i would like to see time of audio file when phrase was spoken by person is it possible or not?

Comment: I am not sure about that one, post this as another question and somebody will help you with that.